# How do I safely use OracleDriver.defaultConnection() in a multithreaded Java Application?

Tags: java, multithreading, oracle11g, jvm, database-connection

I have a multithreaded application which uses OracleDriver.defaultConnection() to connect to the database.
This line of code is used in multiple code blocks which are accessed by different threads. 
I am getting the error : **Java Thread Deadlock detected**

This is a sample piece of code :

```
    private void function1() {
         //something here
         Connection conn = OracleDriver.defaultConnection();

         // something here
         conn.execute();
         conn.close();
   }
```

Second piece of code which is in a separate class :

```
    private void function2() {

         //something here
         Connection conn = OracleDriver.defaultConnection();

         // something here
         conn.execute();
         conn.close();
    }
```

How do I make this connection "thread-safe"?
Also, I read that defaultConnection() returns a static object. So can this be caused due to the connection being closed by one thread while the other thread is using it?

I cannot use any connection method which requires me to input the database username and password.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java provides many ways for dealing with concurrency(synchronized, ReentrantLock, ReadWriteLock)

Considering the documentation which says:

> The oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver class defaultConnection() method is an Oracle extension and always returns the same connection object.

Since it always returns the same connection object you can synchronize on it:

```
Connection conn = OracleDriver.defaultConnection();
synchronized (conn) {
    // something here
    conn.execute();
}
```

However you would need to remove all conn.close() calls due to:

> If you do call the close() method, be aware of the following: All connection instances obtained through the defaultConnection() method, which actually all reference the same connection object, will be closed and unavailable for further use, with state and resource cleanup as appropriate. Executing defaultConnection() afterward would result in a new connection object.
>
> Even though the connection object is closed, the implicit connection to the database will not be closed.